# Why all elements of my list seems to be the same?

Tags: java, list, loops, element

I have the following code:

```
Integer[] lastExchange = new Integer[nColors];
Integer[] newExchange = new Integer[nColors];
while (true) {
    ...
    for (int i=0; i<nColors; i++) {
       lastExchange[i] = newExchange[i];
    }
    ...
    exchanges.add(lastExchange);
    output.log.fine("Exchange:" + lastExchange[0] + "," + lastExchange[1]);
}
for (Integer[] exchange : exchanges) {
    output.log.fine("Exchange:" + exchange[0] + "," + exchange[1]);
}
```

I have two outputs (one in the while loop another one in the for loop). The first output shows me that I do add different arrays to the list. While when i do a double check in the second loop I see that all elements of the `exchange` list are the same (they are equal to the first element of the list).

Does anybody know what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Those dots are fairly important. How do you create/set lastExchange?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As unwind's answer states, you're adding a reference to the same array in every iteration of the loop. You need to create a *new* array each time:

```
// It's not clear where newExchange is actually populated
Integer[] newExchange = new Integer[nColors];
while (true) {
    Integer[] lastExchange = new Integer[nColors];
    ...
    for (int i=0; i<nColors; i++) {
       lastExchange[i] = newExchange[i];
    }
    ...
    exchanges.add(lastExchange);
    output.log.fine("Exchange:" + lastExchange[0] + "," + lastExchange[1]);
}
```

Alternatively, if you're just cloning the array:

```
Integer[] newExchange = new Integer[nColors];
while (true) {
    Integer[] lastExchange = newExchange.clone();
    ...
    exchanges.add(lastExchange);
    output.log.fine("Exchange:" + lastExchange[0] + "," + lastExchange[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What is the type of `lastExchange`? If it's a reference to an object, the the problem is probably exactly that; you just add the same reference to a mutable object, which is then modified and added again.

Since the first loop prints the object before it (presumably) is modified, it prints the proper (different) values.