# Why do I get a "duplicate local variable" error?

Tags: java, duplicates, local-variables

I have a loop in which I calculate a value and add it it a list. So, I do something like that:

```
x = getValue()
values.add(x)
while (true) {
   x = getValue();
   values.add(x)
}
```

I found out that this approach does not work since I add the same instance to the list. In more details, in every cycle of the loop I re-assign a new value to the `x` and doing so I change values of all elements that were already added to the list (so in the end I get a list of identical elements).

To solve this problem I did the following:

```
x = getValue();
Integer[] valueToAdd = new Integer[n];
for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
   valueToAdd[i] = x[i];
}
while (true) {
   x = getValue();
   y = new Integer[n];
   for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
      valueToAdd[i] = x[i];
   }
   values.add(valueToAdd)
}
```

In this way I wanted to create a new instance every time want to add a value to the list. But it does not work since I get a duplicate local variable error.

It is also strange to me that I do not have this error if I declare the same variable many times in the loop. The problem appears only if I first declare a new variable outside the loop and then also in the loop.

Is there a way in Java to re-use the same name for different instances?

**ADDED**
I need to clarify some issues. I did not show all the code. I have the `break` command in the loop (when a new value cannot be generate, I exit the loop). `x` and `value` have `Integer[]` type.

**ADDED 2**
Since it was mentioned that the problem can be in the `getValue()` I need to in more details here. Actually I do not have `getValue()` in my code (I used `getValue()` here to make my example shorter). In my code I had:

```
   Integer[] x = new x[n];
    while (true) {
       for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
          x[i] = y[i];
       }
       values.add(x)
    }
```

And it did not work since in my `values` list I had identical elements (and I know that in the loop on every cycle `x` had a new value).

**ADDED 3**

[Why all elements of my list seems to be the same?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4324754/why-all-elements-of-my-list-seems-to-be-the-same)

Comment: What is the type of 'x'? How come these loops run forever? What is the *actual text* of the error you describe as 'a duplicate local variable error'?

Comment: @EJP, I have the break command in the loop (when a new value cannot be generate, I exit the loop). x and value have Integer[] type.

Comment: This question is *extremely* unclear. Neither does there seem to be a real problem to be solved, nor is there any real code or error messages.

Comment: haven't provided the actual text, nor any code that exhibits any such problem. @Bombe: exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is not what you think it is. For example take a look at this simple program:

```
String x = null;
List<String> l = new ArrayList<String>();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i ++) {
    x = String.valueOf(i);
    l.add(x);
}

System.out.println(l);
```

It prints the numbers from 0 to 9. This is because java is pass-by-value ([check here](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javaqa/2000-05/03-qa-0526-pass.html)). You are not passing the reference to x, you are passing the value of x (in the `add` method).

So the problem lies in the `getValue()` method, which returns the same object.

**Update:** Now the question makes more sense. You are working with the same object `x` everytime, and just changing its state. In order to put different values just move the declaration inside the loop:

```
while (true) {
   Integer[] x = new x[n];
   ...
}
```

If you need it outside the loop, well, simply use another variable there. It does not have to be named `x`. Since you won't be using it inside the loop anyway.

Comment: Sorry, I think thats wrong. Your right java uses pass-by-value but the value of `x` is the reference to the result of `getValue()`. Or do I miss something?

Comment: well, try the above code. If the problem was the local variable it would've printed 9,9,9,9,9,9,9, rather than 0,1,2,3, ...

Comment: @Bozho, can it be that you example works only because in your case `x` is a string and in my case `x` has `Integer[]` type?

Comment: @Bozho, I have added some additional information to my original question (mot about the `getValue()`). More about the problem I had is given here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4324754/why-all-elements-of-my-list-seems-to-be-the-same

Comment: @Bozho, I start to use `x` before the `while` loop. It is why I need to declare it before the loop. If i try to declare it in the loop I get the `duplicate local variable` problem.

Comment: Give it another name.. :)  you don't need the variable outside the loop inside it.

Comment: @Bozho, I use while loop to have a recursive procedure meaning that I use old `x` to generate a new one. If I use two different variable in and out of the loop, than I need to use different variables depending on whether I am the first time in the loop or I made already a cycle. It is why I did not want to have different `x` (one inside the loop and another one for outside the loop).

Comment: @Roman: while loops are not recursive. You are making no sense anywhere here.