# Is it an elegant solution of the duplicate local variable problem?

Tags: java, variables, duplicates, local-variables

```
Integer[] lastExchange = new Integer[nColors];
Integer[] exchangeToAdd = new Integer[nColors];
lastExchange = getValue();
exchangeToAdd = getValue(); 
exchanges.add(exchangeToAdd);

Integer[] newExchange = new Integer[nColors];
while (true) {
   newExchange = getValue(lastExchange);
   Integer[] exchangeToAddForLoop = new Integer[nColors];
   for (int i=0; i<nColors; i++) {
      lastExchange[i] = newExchange[i];
      exchangeToAddForLoop[i] = newExchange[i];
  }
  exchanges.add(exchangeToAddForLoop);
}
```

**ADDED**

What I am trying to do with this code? I need to populate (fill in) the list called `exchanges`. The first element of the list is `lastExchange`. My problem with the code is that I always need to create two duplicates of an variable (it is why I think that the code is not elegant but I cannot find a better solution). For example, in the very beginning I create `lastExchange` and then I create `exchangeToAdd` (that has the same value as `lastExchange`). The same happens in the loop. I create `lastExchange` and then I create `exchangeToAddForLoop`. I do so because I cannot add `lastExchange` to the list because it will be modified latter.

**ADDED 2**

Here is my problem. I have the code like that:

```
Integer[] e  = getValue();
Integer[] e1 = getValue();  // <-- I do not like that.
exchanges.add(e1);          // <-- I do not like that.
while (true) {
   Integer[] e_new = getValue(e);
   Integer[] e2 = new Integer[nColors]; // <-- I do not like that.
   for (int i=0; i<nColors; i++) {
      e[i] = e_new[i];
      e2[i] = e_new[i]; // <-- I do not like that.
  }
  exchanges.add(e2); // <-- I do not like that.
}
```

and I need to calculate `e1` and `e2` additionally to the calculation of `e`.

Comment: Elegant? I don't think so. You are needlessly creating objects that you never use, and your loop never ends. What is the 'duplicate local variable problem'?

Comment: Probably related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4344051/why-do-i-get-a-duplicate-local-variable-error

Comment: @sje397, where do I create objects that I never use?

Comment: @Roman - look at the 1st and 3rd lines - you create an array, then overwrite it immediately with the return value of `getValue`. You can see what you've done wrong by looking at e.g. Jon Skeet's code below.

Comment: @sje397, OK I got it. I agree that it is done in a bad way. But is it OK that I duplicate `lastExchange` before the loop and in the loop. It was my main problem.

Comment: are you talking about duplicate objects?
If so, you have to clone it with deep-copy. And also please change your question's subject, it is misleading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is inelegant code in at least two ways:

- Most of your local variables are being assigned values which are then immediately overwritten
- Your `newExchange` variable could be declared more deeply nested.

So without changing any behaviour, here's a nicer version:

```
Integer[] lastExchange = getValue();
Integer[] exchangeToAdd = getValue();
exchanges.add(exchangeToAdd);

while (true) {
   Integer[] newExchange = getValue(lastExchange);
   Integer[] exchangeToAddForLoop = new Integer[nColors];
   for (int i=0; i<nColors; i++) {
      lastExchange[i] = newExchange[i];
      exchangeToAddForLoop[i] = newExchange[i];
   }
   exchanges.add(exchangeToAddForLoop);
}
```

Next we come to the problem that you haven't told us what any of this code is meant to be doing, nor what you mean by "the duplicate local variable problem". Oh, and as pointed out in the comments, your loop never terminates.

Comment: So, the main objection against the code is that I do not assign the values to the variable when I create them (variables)? Why it is better to declare `newExchange` more deeply nested? In this case I create and assign on every cycle while in my example I just assign in every cycle. My main problem with the code is that I always need to create a duplicate of the `lastExchange` (before the loop it is `exchangeToAdd` in the loop it is `exchangeToAddForLoop`). It is why I think that code is not elegant. But may be there is no way to make it more elegant.

Comment: @Roman: Code is generally clearer when you limit the scope of variables as much as possible - it makes it obvious that you're not using it outside the loop. Without knowing what your code is really trying to do, it's very hard to know how to improve it.

Comment: @Jon Skeet, OK thank you. I understand the problems that you mentioned (I need to assign values to the variables when I declare them and I need to move declaration of `newExchange` to the loop). But my main question was if it is OK that I duplicate the `lastExchnage`? I have extended my original question to clarify what my code is trying to do.

Comment: @Roman: We don't know what `getValue()` does - is there any reason you can't call `exchanges.add(getValue(e))` for example? Does it create a new array itself, or not?

Comment: @Jon Skeet, yes `getValue()` creates a new array. Actually I do not have the `getValue()` in my code, instead of that, in my loop, I have several lines that use `lastExchange` array to generate a new array (`newExchange`). I put `getValue` in the example just to make it shorter. Before the loop, instead of `getValue()` I also have several lines to generate the value for `lastExchange`.

Comment: @Roman: If you're already creating a new array, why are you bothering to copy it?

Comment: @Jon Skeet, I agree, there is no point to create the `exchangeToAddForLoop` I can add `newExchange` to the loop and I should not worry that in the next cycle I will have another value for the `newExchange` because it will be a new variable that has nothing to do with the elements which are already in the list.

Answer (score 3):

Without discussing your code, when you have duplicate variable errors, you can always use {}.

This does not compile

```
            int a=0;
            a++;


            int a=0;
            a++;
```

this does:

```
        {
            int a=0;
            a++;
        }
        {
            int a=0;
            a++;
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

@Jon's simplification is the safest, however I suspect it can be simplified further.

```
exchanges.add(getValue());

while (true) { // forever??
   // do you need null values or can you use int[]
   int[] newExchange = getValue(exchanges.get(exchanges.size()-1);
   // do you need to add a copy, if not then clone() can be dropped.
   exchanges.add(newExchange.clone());
}
```